# IE9 says Syntax Error but not where?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, syntax-error

So, I have a large project with a bunch of javascript stuff going on.

Now I did some testing with IE9 and on one event triggered AJAX-operation it aborts and tells me

```
Syntax Error: Expected ')'
```

but that's all it says. It leaves me without any clue about where to start looking.

I'm using Dojo for most of the things I do and at this particular point I'm retrieving JSON-data with the AJAX-request. But I've ruled out an error in the JSON-string, simply because JSON ususally does not contain brackets `()`, right?

There also is a `console.log(data)` right after the request should be completed, but it doesn't fire either. And I don't see any fancy bracketwork before that, that could make IE lose it's mind. But I might still be looking at the wrong spot, just trying to give as much info as possible here.

(btw: Firefox is fine with everything. No errors or warnings; everything runs just fine)

What's the best way to debug this or possible causes?

Comment: Reduce the problem to its simplest form that still creates the error.

Comment: Do you have the console open in IE when you run the code?

Comment: @j08691 Yes, I'm using the debugging console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the response from AJAX after all.

IE had problems sending all the `GET` parameters resulting in an error message being mixed with the JSON code. I still don't understand why it expected a `)` but fixing the response fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Versions of Internet Explorer from 8 upwards have a built in debugger which is similar to Firebug - press **F12** to launch it (by default).

The standard error reporting is terrible, but the debugger will give you much more accurate feedback on where the error occurred.

(My take on this is that the standard Javascript error handling assumes you're a typical IE user and gives you very little feedback.  Firing up the dev tools lets it know you can handle the truth.)

Comment: It's exactly that debugging console (even the "Console"-tab) that's telling me the error but not where. And I'm still trying to figure out when the debugger breaks and when not. It's set to "break on error" but it never breaks.